# Can I Create Many-to-Many Relationships Within Embedded Documents in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, many-to-many, modeling

Given the following class diagram:
[image: Class Diagram]

How should I approach which should be collections and which should be embedded? Since there is a 1..N relationship between Play/Scene and Play/Character, I would normally embed those documents in Play. But the use case is that I also need to track which characters appear in which scene. Would this dictate that now Scene and Character need to be their own collection or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Many plays have many characters and scenes and those characters have many appearances in many plays is my immediate thought on that schema.

However to respond to your question. Doing many to many on embedded would not be a wise idea, most likely infact a bad (maybe even terrible) idea.

I would split the commonly included entities into separate tables.

Comment: I think you're saying something similar to the above answer. You wouldn't want to the model to have a character appear in more than one play. A play's characters would belong only to that play.

Answer (score 0):

I think the short answer to your headline question is no. You can't have a document that is embedded in multiple places. It's like trying to have an egg that is inside of two shells simultaneously. In my head I think of mongodb relations as onions (layers = embeds) with threads that connect to other onions (thread = reference). It might be a screwy analogy but it works for me.

Let's say that Characters -- even those with the same name -- are unique to the play they are in. So those would be embedded.

Scenes look like a clear example of an embedded array. You'd never have a scene that appeared in multiple plays.

Appearance should be embedded in a Scene for the same reasons as Scenes are embedded in Plays. Appearance would reference the character as well. Is there ever an Appearance that isn't referencing a Character? I'd think not, but not sure.

So I'd do it like this (pseudo-modeling):

```
Play { 
  embeds-many Characters 
  embeds-many Scenes }  

Scene { embeds-many Appearances }

Appearance { references a Character } 

Character { }
```

I think it's definitely possible to reference the Character from the Appearance, you just need to store the ID of the character inside the Appearance. The next question is what language you are working in... If you're in Rails, I personally like Mongoid.

Comment: You wouldn't want to have a character appear in many plays. A character's appearance would be limited to one play. Even in the example you give (Shakespeare), Falstaff is a different person in Henry IV I/II and Merry Wives of Windsor. No, you'd want a character to belong to one play only.

Comment: Maybe I asked the question poorly, I don't want to embed a document in two places, I was wondering if it was possible to have a relationship between two embedded documents in the same containing document.

Comment: I haven't decided on a language yet. I'm leaning toward Node because I like the idea of staying in js front-to-back. Suggestions?

Comment: @KevDog it's a good idea. Personally, I love love love some Coffeescript and if you already know any Ruby, coffee is easy to pick up. With Node you can do Coffeescript front to back. If only there was a native coffeescript compiler for mongo...